# PHP Fatal error break;

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress plugin that fetches stock quote feed from Yahoo finance. IT JUST HAPPENS VERY RARELY... OTHERWISE IT DON'T SHOW UP. I randomly get fatal error saying on line 140 ... and line 140 is break; i am copying below quote to understand the code. EDIT: NOW I HAVE PUT THE ENTIRE PHP FILE...!!

```
<?php
```

/*
Plugin Name: Stock Quotes
Plugin URI: http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/stock-quotes-plugin-for-wordpress/
Description: Displays stock quotes on your website
Author: Dagon Design
Version: 1.0.1
Author URI: http://www.dagondesign.com
*/

$ddsq_version = '1.0.1';

// Setup defaults if options do not exist
add_option('ddsq_format', '**%NAME%:** %LAST% ( %CHANGE% )');
add_option('ddsq_up_color', '00BB00');
add_option('ddsq_down_color', 'FF0000');
add_option('ddsq_update_time', '10');

function ddsq_add_option_pages() {
    if (function_exists('add_options_page')) {
        add_options_page('Stock Quotes', 'DDStockQuotes', 8, **FILE**, 'ddsq_options_page');
    }
}

function ddsq_options_page() {

```
global $ddsq_version;

if (isset($_POST['set_defaults'])) {
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>';

    update_option('ddsq_format', '<strong>%NAME%</strong> %LAST% [<strong>%CHANGE%</strong>]');
    update_option('ddsq_up_color', '00BB00');
    update_option('ddsq_down_color', 'FF0000');
    update_option('ddsq_update_time', '10');

    echo 'Default Options Loaded!';
    echo '</strong></p></div>';

} else if (isset($_POST['info_update'])) {

    update_option('ddsq_format', (string) $_POST["ddsq_format"]);
    update_option('ddsq_up_color', (string) $_POST["ddsq_up_color"]);
    update_option('ddsq_down_color', (string) $_POST["ddsq_down_color"]);
    update_option('ddsq_update_time', $_POST["ddsq_update_time"]);

    echo 'Configuration Updated!';
    echo '</strong></p></div>';

} ?>

<div class=wrap>

<h2>Stock Quotes v<?php echo $ddsq_version; ?></h2>

<p>For information and updates, please visit:<br />
<a href="http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/stock-quotes-plugin-for-wordpress/">http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/stock-quotes-plugin-for-wordpress/</a></p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="info_update" id="info_update" value="true" />


<h3>Usage</h3>
<p>There are two ways you can display quotes:</p>
<p><strong>1) In a post or page</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
[stock MSFT]</p>
<p><strong>2) In a template file</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
&lt;?php echo ddsq_get_quote('MSFT'); ?&gt;</p>


<h3>Options</h3>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4">

<tr valign="top"><td width="13%">
    <strong>Output Format </strong>
</td><td align="left">
    <input name="ddsq_format" type="text" size="100" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(get_option('ddsq_format'))) ?>"/>
    <br />Placeholders for data: <strong>%NAME% %LAST% %CHANGE%</strong>
</td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="13%">
    <strong>Up Color </strong>
</td><td align="left">
    <input name="ddsq_up_color" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo get_option('ddsq_up_color') ?>"/>
     Color to use for price change when up (leave blank to disable)
</td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="13%">
    <strong>Down Color </strong>
</td><td align="left">
    <input name="ddsq_down_color" type="text" size="7" value="<?php echo get_option('ddsq_down_color') ?>"/>
     Color to use for price change when down (leave blank to disable)
</td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="13%">
    <strong>Update Time </strong>
</td><td align="left">
    <input name="ddsq_update_time" type="text" size="3" value="<?php echo get_option('ddsq_update_time') ?>"/>
    Number of minutes to wait, before fetching updated stock prices
</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="set_defaults" value="<?php _e('Load Default Options'); ?> &raquo;" />
    <input type="submit" name="info_update" value="<?php _e('Update options'); ?> &raquo;" />
</div>

</form>
</div><?php
```

}

function ddsq_get_quote($symb) {

```
$up_color = trim(get_option('ddsq_up_color'));
$down_color = trim(get_option('ddsq_down_color'));
$quote_format = stripslashes(get_option('ddsq_format'));
$update_time = trim(get_option('ddsq_update_time'));

$update_time = $update_time * 60;
$t_out = '';
$time_diff = '';

// Trying to open local cached file first
$file_path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/" . $symb . ".txt";
if (file_exists($file_path)){
    $time_diff = date('U') - filemtime($file_path);
}

$lf = @fopen($file_path, "r");
if (($lf == FALSE) || ($time_diff >= $update_time)) {
    $url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" . $symb . "&f=sl1c1";
    $fp = @fopen($url, "r");
    if ($fp == FALSE) {
        #$t_out = 'Error opening: ' . htmlspecialchars($url);
        break;
    } else {
        $array = @fgetcsv($fp , 4096 , ', ');
        @fclose($fp);
        $sq_name = $array[0];
        $sq_last = $array[1];
        $sq_change = $array[2];

        $col = NULL;
        if (($sq_change[0] == '-') && ($down_color != '')) {
            $col = $down_color;
        } else if (($sq_change[0] == '+') && ($up_color != '')) {
            $col = $up_color;
        }

        if ($col !== NULL) {
            $sq_change =  '<span style="color: #' . $col . ';">' . $sq_change . '</span>';
        }

        $t_out = $quote_format;
        $t_out = str_replace('%NAME%', $sq_name, $t_out);
        $t_out = str_replace('%LAST%', $sq_last, $t_out);
        $t_out = str_replace('%CHANGE%', $sq_change, $t_out);

        $cache_file = fopen($file_path, "w+");
        fwrite($cache_file, $t_out);
    }
} else {
    fclose($lf);
    $t_out = file_get_contents($file_path);
    if ($t_out == FALSE){
        echo "ERROR opening cache file";
    }
}

return $t_out;
```

}

function ddsq_process($content) {

```
$results = array();

preg_match_all("/\[\s?stock\s?(.*)\s?\]/", $content, $results);

$i = 0;
foreach ($results[0] as $r) {

    $content = str_replace($r, ddsq_get_quote($results[1][$i]), $content);
    $i++;
}

return $content;
```

}

add_filter('the_content', 'ddsq_process');
add_action('admin_menu', 'ddsq_add_option_pages');

?>

Comment: The fatal error just says "on line 140"? That's strange.

Comment: Is there a `for`/`while` loop there, because otherwise there is no reason for a `break` in there.

Comment: Yeah, posting all of the code would be useful. You've cut it off.

Comment: just posted more code.. i guess it's more clear now.!!

Comment: @Imran Jafri Everybody is curious if you are using a `for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure`, see the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php). As long as there´s code before what you've posted, we won´t know.

Comment: posted the complete PHP file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no loop or control structure (like `switch`), that accepts `break;` within itself. I guess, that you sometimes call this code within a loop. In this case `break;` is allowed. But sometimes it's not. At all `break;` doesn't make any sense within an `if`-block.

Comment: so should i comment out break; ??

Comment: "I guess, that you sometimes call this code within a loop. In this case break; is allowed." PHP really allows you to do that?

Comment: @Imran: Remove it completely. @phant0m: In fact thats the main purpose: To break a loop.

Comment: @KingCrunch: I misinterpreted that. I thought you meant, calling a function that contained a `break` which would exit the function and the loop... I was really puzzled :) @mhitza: I get an error when doing it with `include` as well (and I hoped to get one).

Comment: I have now posted the entire php file.

Comment: @phant0m: I didn't know, if it works with functions and `break` in it, so I was curious enough to try it out and no, this doesn't work :) But if the `include`-thing don't work neither, I guess the affected code part with the `break` in it just don't get executed (meaning: `$fp` is not equal `false`).

Comment: i have posted the complete PHP file now.. should i remove break;

Comment: @Imran: Once more "yes". I don't even understand, why you put one there.

Comment: Heh, so you just made that somewhat daring statement? :) It's cool though, this left me puzzled and I was like, oh noes... please PHP, I already know enough dirty secrets about you...

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if a file-pointer can evaluate to `false`, but when checking `fopen` for errors, you need to use:

```
if ($fp === FALSE)
```

Apart from that, take a look at @mhitza's comment.

Comment: I am totally Newbie this plugin was made by my dev. I am just trying to fix it before bugging him :)